# xctool build with today extension

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, ios8-today-widget, xctool

we have an app integrated with today extension, we use xctool and Jenkins to do continuous build and in-house distribution.

In command line, before we use

```
xctool -workspace our_workspace.xcworkspace -scheme app_schme -xcconfig path_to_xcconfig -configuration Release build archive -archivePath path_to_archive
```

to generate archive and then export to .ipa, it works fine.

But right now with today extension, we have to build it with another scheme and xcconfig, we put certificate and provisioning profile in xcconfig, as today extension is a new target and should built with its own certificate and provisioning profile, I'm wondering how to achieve using xctool.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I finally managed to export ipa files via xcodebuild. Since the xctool is built upon xcodebuild, this answer might help.

First of all, when you create an extension, the extension's target will be embedded into your main app's scheme.

[image]

So, there is no need to use two schemes.

Then, in your project settings page, create a new configuration, say `AdHoc`. And then you can set a new `Provisioning Profile` in both of your target's build settings.

[image]

(project settings)

[image]

(the build settings of one target)

Then set the right provisioning profiles for your targets (And you'd better set the `code sign identity` to automatic, so that Xcode can determine which code sign identity is to be used).

Next step, you can archive your app using xcodebuild with the new configuration you just created above:

```
xcodebuild -project Extension\ Demo.xcodeproj -scheme Extension\ Demo -sdk iphoneos -archivePath ./Build/extension-demo.xcarchive -configuration AdHoc archive
```

In this step, the codesign will sign two of your targets separately by the provisioning profiles you specified.

Finally, export the `.xcarchive` file to `ipa`, again using xcodebuild;

```
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ./Build/extension-demo.xcarchive -exportPath ./Build/extension-demo.ipa -exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity
```

Notice that `-exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity` is set, so that xcodebuild will not re-sign your ipa, and the code signature in the xcarchive file is preserved.

Comment: "Then set the right provisioning profiles for your targets" how to do it via xcodebuild command line?

Comment: You don't do this with xcodebuild command, instead you need to set them in Xcode's Build Settings in the configuration that you created in step 1 (see pic 3). You only need to specify the configuration to xcodebuild and don't care what provisioning profile it is.

Comment: may be you right. I've just put it as you said. Not found other ways. Thanks.

Comment: `-exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity` will also preserve the original provisioning profile? I doubt. `-exportProvisioningProfile` is required for `xcodebuild -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa` IMHO

Comment: as of Xcode 9, I get an error when trying to include -exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity.  "xcodebuild: error: invalid option '-exportWithOriginalSigningIdentity'"