# Making IPA from command line xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, ipa, xcode9

i have many projects embedded in single main project, i am trying to automate the build process. but issue is that i cant make build using command line.

```
Clean project
xcodebuild clean -project TestingCommandLine.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -alltargets

Make Archive
xcodebuild archive -project TestingCommandLine.xcodeproj -scheme "TestingCommandLine" -configuration Debug -archivePath myApp.xcarchive

Build IPA
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath myApp.xcarchive -exportPath myApp.ipa -exportOptionsPlist exportOptions.plist
```

the same process works with simple project which does not have any dependencies.

The following build commands failed:
    Ld watchos/Watch\ Extension.appex/iskanWatch\ Extension normal armv7k
(1 failure)

This is the actual failure error comes when i try to build.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27445649/xctool-build-with-today-extension